# Existence of reduced Groebner basis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, computational-algebra, groebner-basis

In my class notes there is a Theorem saying: Every non zero ideal of the ring $F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ has a reduced Groebner Basis. Unfortunately there is no proof. Can someone give the proof or refer to somewhere where I can find it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Several results on the first page of a google search for "reduced Grobner basis" give proofs or references. Did you consult any of them?

Comment: I found lots of examples and applications but no proof for the existence of the basis, only its uniqueness

Comment: You can find an introduction to Groebner basis in the textbook *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms
- An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*, by Cox, Little and O'Shea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition a Groebner basis $G$ is *reduced* when for every $g \in G$,

- $LC(g) = 1$, and
- $LM(g)$ divides no monomial of any element of $G \setminus \{g\}$.

Here $LC(g)$ denotes the leading coefficient of $g$ and $LM(g)$ denotes the leading monomial of $g$, and of course these notions (and the notion of a Groebner basis) depend on a chosen monomial ordering.

Given an arbitrary Groebner basis $G'=(f_1,\ldots,f_s)$ we construct a reduced Groebner basis as follows:

1. Remove all "redundant" $f_i$ with $LM(f_j) \mid LM(f_i)$ for some $j$.
2. Replace each $f_i$ by $f_i/LC(f_i)$, to normalize all the leading coefficients.
3. Replace each $f_i$ by a [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Reduction) of $f_i$ by the set of remaining $f_j$ with $j \neq i$.

The last step affects only the non-leading terms (due to step 1), and it achieves exactly the second requirement for being reduced. QED.

Comment: announcement regarding quality standards."
This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: There is no duplicate, and improvements were already suggested and implemented (focusing on existence).

Comment: Then you need to wait for the asker to follow suggestions offered.  If the asker fails to improve the question, don't answer it.